# How to recover header cell data from HTML table which are dynamically added with ngFor directive

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to retrieve the cell data from the header of my array in my typescript .ts file. Knowing that these `<th>` cells are dynamically generated using the `ngFor` directive. I only get the column names written in hard (action, a, b, c, d) but not the other names generated dynamically from my API. I would like to retrieve column names dynamically generated.

**Here is my HTML file:**

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead id="thead">
    <tr id="head">
      <th class="columnName">Action</th>
      <th class="columnName">a</th>
      <th class="columnName">b</th>
      <th class="columnName">c</th>
      <th class="columnName">d</th>
      <th scope="col" *ngFor="let column of table.columns" class="columnName">{{ column.name }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**Here is my component.ts file**

```js
getColumnName() {
    const theadRow = document.getElementsByClassName('columnName');
    // const thList = theadRow.children;
    console.log(theadRow);

    for (let i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
      console.log(theadRow[i].innerHTML);
    }
```

**Here is my result:**
[image]

Comment: You can ready those directly from `table.columns`.

Comment: Yes but if I do that, I get array of object and I only want column name.

Comment: table.columns.map(x=>x.name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `var names = table.columns.map(col => col.name)` to extract the names out.

Here's more info on [Array.map()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_map.htm)